# Half carry flag emulating the GBA

Tags: c++, emulation, game-boy-advance

I've seen some documentation on detecting the HALF CARRY flag changes for the GBA. I'm writing an emulator in C++ and i'm having a hard time thinking on how to detect HALF CARRY flag changes when i'm **subtracting** two different numbers.
(This should be apparent also in shift and rotate operations, ADD has been well documented here on Stack Overflow and on different guides).

So far, I have this function that detects if an operation triggers the HALF CARRY to be set (I'm positive this works only with addition):

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
static constexpr bool HalfCarryOnAddition(uint8_t first_num, uint8_t second_num)
{
    return (((first_num & 0xF) + (second_num & 0xF)) & 0x10) == 0x10;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand now what half carry essentially is -> Its a check for the carry bit on HALF of the size of the type you're looking for.

The implementations for ADD, SUB for the HALF-CARRY flags for both uint8_t and uint16_t is:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
static constexpr bool HalfCarryOnAddition(uint8_t first_num, uint8_t second_num)
{
    return (((first_num & 0x0F) + (second_num & 0x0F)) & 0x10) == 0x10;
}

static constexpr bool HalfCarryOnAddition(uint16_t first_num, uint16_t second_num)
{
    return (((first_num & 0x00FF) + (second_num & 0x00FF)) & 0x0100) == 0x0100;
}

static constexpr bool HalfCarryOnSubtration(uint8_t first_num, uint8_t second_num)
{
    return (int)(first_num & 0x0F) - (int)(second_num & 0x0F) < 0;
}

static constexpr bool HalfCarryOnSubtration(uint16_t first_num, uint16_t second_num)
{
    return (int)(first_num & 0x00FF) - (int)(second_num & 0x00FF) < 0;
}
```